# Webpack+Babel | C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory | JS

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

hope you doing great.

I just tried using babel and webpack but for some reason it doesn't work.
I even bought a new computer but no change...

Every time I start running the webpack command (node_modules/.bin/webpack). I am getting the error:
**C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory**

The same happens when I using babel without webpack:
**The "node_modules" command is either misspelled or
could not be found.**
(I am calling a start script from package.json file here - node_modules/.bin/babel ./src/index.js -o ./dist/assets/bundle.js)

The path clearly exsists on my computer.
Also I checked several times that I am in the correct folder in my terminal...
My package.json file looks like this:

```js
{
      "name": "chapter_19",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "babel": "node_modules/.bin/babel ./src/index.js -o ./dist/assets/bundle.js"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
        "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "webpack": "^5.72.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
      }
    }
```

Here's my webpack file:

```
  const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry:':/src/index.js',
    output:{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
}
```

And my files/folders
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoK53.png)

Does someome maybe  what's going on here?

Help would be greatly greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: `./node_modules/.bin/babel`? Buying a new computer because of a bug seems a little drastic FWIW.

Comment: Make sure you use bash and not Windows' command prompt. You are using bash syntax in your commands. Also, `:/src/index.js` doesn't look right. Did you mean `./src/index.js`?